# Separating points following different linear regressions

Tags: statistics, regression, cluster-analysis, linear-regression, pca

Given a two variables with the same number of observations, you will apparently see they follow three linear regressions in the scatter plot. How could you separate them into three groups with different linear fittings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There exist specialized clustering algorithms for this.

Google for "correlation clustering".

If they all go through 0, then it may be easier to apply the proper feature transformation to make them separable. So don't neglect preprocessing. It's the most important part.

Comment: Searched for a while, nothing really helpful found.

Comment: What about ORCLUS, LMCLUS, CASH?

Comment: And don't forget preprocessing. Can you define a better derived feature like V2/V1?

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the slope of the segment between any pairs of points, so with `n` points you get `n(n+1)/2` slopes values, and then use a clustering algorithm.

It is the same idea which is behind the [Theil–Sen estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator)

It just came to my mind and seems worth to give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a mixture of regressions. There are several packages to do this. One of them is FlexMix, while not very satisfying. I put what I got and expected in below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem partly. We can use a r package flexmix to achieve this as the lowest panel shows. The package works fine with another  two known-fitting groups of data. The seperating ratio can reach as high as 90% with fitting coefficients close to the known coefs.